# Find a specific index read

Tags: hpcc-ecl

I'm having an issue with a roxie query when being called via an API. I've tested the query in HThor and the web service on 8002 and it runs perfectly. When calling it from an API I'm getting memory pool exhausted. The only clue I have in the logs is

Pool memory exhausted: pool id 0 exhausted, requested 1 heap(4095/4294967295) global(4096/4096) WM(1..128) (in Index Read 40)"

How can I find out which index read this is referring to?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

The index read is indicated in the brackets - it is activity 40 in the graph.

The error message is indicating that all of the memory has been exhausted (4096 pages of 256K each).  It is likely to be an index read that has a poor filter condition, returns a large number of rows and is feeding into an activity that needs all the input rows to process it (e.g. a sort).

Comment: Thanks very much Gavin. I hope all is well with you.